# Edit Discord message with the before content replaced

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm currently developing a Discord bot with discord.py. I made a command named `underscored` and the goal is to edit each message the bot sends with just replacing the spaces by underscores. Here's an example:

```
User: /test
Bot: This is a test command.
User: /underscored
User: /test
Bot: This_is_a_test_command.
```

So here's the command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def underscored(ctx):
    underscored == True
```

And on the other hand, here's the on_message event I made:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message, before):
    if underscored == True:
        await message.edit(content=before.replace(' ', '_'))
```

Now, here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'before'
```

Can someone help me? I quite don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Why do you think `on_message` can take a second argument? It'can't

Comment: `before` and `after` arguments go inside [on_message_edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message_edit#discord.on_message_edit) function and not inside ``on_message``

Comment: Thanks Conner Wolf 08, so is it not possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: If "what I want to do" is adding random parameters to library methods, then no. Where would the value of `before` even come from? You can definitely just set a flag in a command and check the value of that in another command, but this is not the way to do that. You may want to learn some more Python before creating a Discord bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because `on_message` event takes only one argument, which is the message (`discord.Message` class). You can refere the documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)

You will have to implement it to every command manually, instead of using the `on_message` event

```py
# global variable that can be accessed by every command
underscored_s = False

@bot.command()
async def underscored(ctx):
    global underscored_s

    # toggle underscored status, turn on if off, turn off if on
    if underscored_s is True:
        underscored_s = False
        await ctx.send("changed underscored to False")
    else:
        underscored_s = True
        await ctx.send("changed underscored to True")

@bot.command()
async def on_message(ctx):
    global underscored_s

    message = "This is a test command."
    if underscored_s is True:
        await ctx.send(message)
    else:
        await ctx.send(message.replace(' ', '_'))
```

`on_message` event is to be used when a new message is sent by a user, to process it by the bot. I dont think that it can be used to edit the message sent by the bot as a reply to the `on_message` event